# What is wrong with this piece of code that gcc will not convert it to .exe

Tags: c++

I can't seem to find an answer to this question, because it's too open, I guess.

I am currently learning C++ with a for dummies book. The book is a bit old (2001), but still very helpful. I was busy with this piece of code and I tried to convert it in cmd with the line `gcc -o conversion conversion.cpp` (my file is called conversion).

When I try to convert it it says at the end of a long text:

```
failed: invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int arg, char* pszArgs[])

    {   
        int loopCount;
        cout << "Enter the amount of loops: ";
        cin >> loopCount;

        while (loopCount > 0)
        {
            loopCount = loopCount - 1;
            cout << "Still " << loopCount << " to go/n";

        return 0;
        }
        }
```

Please help, I want to find out what's wrong. I can't find it anywhere...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't tell me the book told you to run that command (though considering the bad rap the book gets, I wouldn't be surprised). As mentioned, it's wrong, but it also doesn't even use any warnings.

Comment: If looks like you've placed `return 0;` inside the `while` statement. Did you really intend to do that? If you indent your code properly, such mistakes will become easier to spot. A small nitpick is that you since you're not using the arguments to `main` you could use the shorter signature `int main()`. You can also leave out the `return 0;` altogether for the `main` function. I'm not so sure that learning C++ from such an old book is a good idea, considering how much the language has evolved since then (especially with the C++11 standard).

Comment: Use either C I/O (using stdio.h) or C++ I/O (using iostream).  Don't mix them.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, it's fixed now. The problem is that that book was the only one I could find in my local library. By the way, the for dummies book told me to use both stdio.h & iostream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `g++` to compile C++ programs, not `gcc`.